# How does Linq return an anonymous type of IQueryable to get its record count?

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

The following Linq query returns an IQueryable of anonymous type:

```
var users2 = from u1 in Users
         join u2 in distribs on u1.pDistribId equals u2.Id
         into temp
         from u3 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new {
             u1.Id,
             u1.UserName,
             u1.pDistribId,
             pUserName = u3 == null ? "" : u3.UserName,
             u1.Phone,
             u1.Name,
             u1.pCustomUser,
             u1.CoName,
             u1.CoPhone,
             u1.Birthday,
             u1.QQ,
             u1.Email,
             u1.SelfIntr
         };
```

To get the number of records for users2, use the following method:

```
var c = users2.Count();
```

Error in result:

> Dbcomparonexpression requires parameters of a comparable type.

How does an IQueryable type like this anonymous type get its record count?

Complete source code：

users：

```
var Users = from u in UserManager.Users
                        where u.Equals("user")
                        select new { u.Id, u.UserName, u.pDistribId, u.Phone, u.Name, u.CoName, u.CoPhone, u.pCustomUser, u.Birthday, u.QQ, u.Email, u.SelfIntr };
```

distribs：

```
var distribs = from u in UserManager.Users
                           where u.Role.Equals("distrib")
                           select new { u.Id, u.UserName, u.pDistribId, u.Phone, u.Name, u.CoName, u.CoPhone, u.pCustomUser, u.Birthday, u.QQ, u.Email, u.SelfIntr };
```

users2:

```
var users2 = (from u1 in Users
             join u2 in distribs on u1.pDistribId equals u2.Id
             into temp
             from u3 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {
                 u1,
                 u3
             }).ToList()
             .Select(x => new {
                 x.u1.Id,
                 x.u1.UserName,
                 x.u1.pDistribId,
                 pUserName = x.u3 == null ? "" : x.u3.UserName,
                 x.u1.Phone,
                 x.u1.Name,
                 x.u1.pCustomUser,
                 x.u1.CoName,
                 x.u1.CoPhone,
                 x.u1.Birthday,
                 x.u1.QQ,
                 x.u1.Email,
                 x.u1.SelfIntr
             });


var c = users2.Count();
```

In this code Still report the same error：

`var users2 = (from u1 in Users`

Answer (score 0):

The error `DbComparisonExpression requires parameters of a comparable type` likely relates to your use of `.Equals()` in `where u.Equals("user")`. It looks like `u` is a class, and you are comparing it to a string. You are comparing two different types.

Answer (score 0):

Use ToList conversion for Linq query results, and sub linq will also be converted

Comment: Calling `.ToList()` on an `IQueryable` evaluates/runs that query, in the same way as calling `Count()` on that  `IQueryable`.